# Html string reader

Tags: c#, .net, html, silverlight

I need to load HTML and parse it, I think that it should be something simple, I pass a string with a "HTML" it reads the string in a Dom like object, so I can search and parse the content of the HTML, facilitating scraping and things like that.

Do you guys know about any thing like that.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for not asking for a regex to do this ;-p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Similar API to `XmlDocument`, for example (from the examples page):

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

(you should also be able to use `LoadHtml` to load a string of html, rather than from a path)

Comment: Do you know whether that compiles against the Silverlight libraries?

Comment: @Anthony - no clue whatsoever, sorry.

Comment: I don't have access to this things in WCF. I had to do a line by line parse. very dumb and hard.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running in-browser, you should be able to use the Html DOM Bridge, load the HTML into it, and walk the DOM Tree for that.